# What are the ways in which I can provide the description for the Spring Boot Configuration Processor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configuration-metadata) gives an illustration of providing javadoc comments on fields to have the generated configuration metadata JSON file include a description. Example of code snippet:

```java
public static class Server {

    /**
     * The IP of the database server
     */
    private String ip;

    /**
     * The Port of the database server.
     * The Default value is 443.
     * The allowed values are in the range 400-4000.
     */
    @Min(400)
    @Max(800)
    private int port = 443;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Is there any way I can provide the description using an annotation?

Something like:

```java
public static class Server {
   @Description("some string") private String ip;
}
```

Or is there any other way I can add the description - rather than relying on Javadoc?